# How to check running processes version reading "ps aux" output in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have coded a C++ program that it reads the output from "ps aux" command to obtain the full list of the processes running. I would like to know how to get the processes version in order to check if one of these have been updated

Comment: What do you mean by process version?

Comment: the version of the software running

Comment: I'm afraid, that's software-dependent. You could, for example: 1) try to run the same binary with `--version` argument (not quite reliable) or 2) figure out the package it's installed from and take the package version. But there's no generic way as far as I know.

Comment: I agree but not all processes support `--version` argument

Comment: What means that a process has been updated ? That the binary has changed ?

Comment: it means that if a program running has changed his version, e.g. from 1.0 to 1.1, it means that this program has been updated, for this reason I would like to obtain the version of running programs to check if one or various have changed their versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could obtain the version of the actual software running with the following steps:

1. Listing the processes running with `ps aux`
2. Check what is the package corresponding with each processes with `dpkg-query --search pathCommand`
3. Listing the package name and version with `dpkg -s <packagename>`